# ldap.rememberMe.usernameMapper.userDnBase (multiple instances of?) (searchSubtree search capability)

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-plugin, remember-me, spring-security-ldap

I have a Grails application that is successfully using the latest ***spring-security-core:2.0-RC4*** and ***spring-security-ldap:2.0-RC2***. Users can login perfectly using
***grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.search.base*** setting for LDAP login authentication.

There is a different setting for the rememberMe *userDnBase* (mapper) and that setting is:
***grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.rememberMe.usernameMapper.userDnBase***

The LDAP authentication ***grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.search.base*** is set to ***ou=people,dc=sitcudy,dc=edu***. As mentioned above - the logins work fine because there is a property called ***searchSubtree*** that I have set to true. Unfortunately, the ***searchSubtree*** setting does not hold true and carry through consistently within the 'remember-me' portion of the code ***(.ldap.rememberMe*)***. The remember-me portion of the code uses a map for the base DN,  ***grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.rememberMe.usernameMapper.userDnBase***
 so I put in a string in the ***config.groovy*** file (the same as for the authentication piece) to map to the base DN of ***ou=people,dc=sitcudy,dc=edu***.... which gets mapped to the DN for the LDAP user look up upon returning to the application for persistence cookie login.

Here's where my problem comes in, most users are segregated into different DIT's in our LDAP system. For example, some uses are in ***ou=staff,ou=people,dc=sitcudy,dc=edu*** while other users are in ***ou=students,ou=people,dc=sitcudy,dc=edu*** therefore, because of the remember me mapping, upon returning to the application, once verifying the cookie, the code tries to bind users in this format, ***uid=reuben_marcus,ou=people,dc=sitcudy,dc=edu*** which doesn't exist. What does exist is ***uid=reuben_marcus,ou=staff,ou=people,dc=sitcudy,dc=edu*** therefore the cookie is destroyed and the login (***IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED***) never occurs.

If I change ***grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.rememberMe.usernameMapper.userDnBase***
 to ***ou=staff,ou=people,dc=sitcudy,dc=edu*** the remember me functionality works perfect for all staff members, but it doesn't work for all other people - students, faculty etc.

The main setting in question below for me in this issue is:
***grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.rememberMe.usernameMapper.userDnBase***

Since this is just a mapping and there isn't allowance for multiple ***userDNBases*** or ***searchSubtree*** search.. **How is the ‘remember-me’ code supposed to find users that do not fall into this base DN setting...??**

I wonder if I'm doing something wrong or if this is a feature request to have the ‘remember me’ code have options for multiple mapping ***userDNBases*** or allow it to have a ***searchSubtree*** search capability.

Relevant settings from my config.groovy:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.mapper.roleAttributes = 'sitPriRole,uid'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.context.managerDn = 'uid=SPS_bind,ou=People,dc=sitcudy,dc=edu'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.context.managerPassword = 'xxx' 
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.context.server = 'ldap://ds01.sitcudy.edu:389'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.authorities.groupSearchBase ='ou=Groups,dc=sitcudy,dc=edu' 


grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.search.base = 'ou=People,dc=sitcudy,dc=edu'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.search.searchSubtree = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.auth.hideUserNotFoundExceptions = false
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.search.attributesToReturn = ['uid', 'sitPriRole', 'mail', 'displayName']
grails.plugin.springsecurity.providerNames = ['ldapAuthProvider', 'anonymousAuthenticationProvider', 'rememberMeAuthenticationProvider']
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.authorities.retrieveGroupRoles = false
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.authorities.retrieveDatabaseRoles = false
grails.plugin.springsecurity.password.algorithm = 'SHA-256'


grails.plugin.springsecurity.rememberMe.persistent = true 
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rememberMe.persistentToken.domainClassName = 'od.PersistentLogin' 


// role-specific LDAP config 
// grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.useRememberMe = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.rememberMe.detailsManager.attributesToRetrieve = null 
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.rememberMe.detailsManager.groupMemberAttributeName = 'uniquemember'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.rememberMe.detailsManager.groupRoleAttributeName = 'cn' 
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.rememberMe.detailsManager.groupSearchBase = 'ou=Groups,dc=sitcudy,dc=edu'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.rememberMe.detailsManager.passwordAttributeName = 'userPassword'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.rememberMe.usernameMapper.userDnBase = 'ou=People,dc=sitcudy,dc=edu'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ldap.rememberMe.usernameMapper.usernameAttribute = 'uid'
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem was mentioned here: [Grails - Spring security plugin ldap: remember me not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22175417/grails-spring-security-plugin-ldap-remember-me-not-working)

I found a workaround for this by registering custom [`TokenBasedRememberMeServices`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.2.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/rememberme/TokenBasedRememberMeServices.html) bean in `resources.groovy`. 
I didn't use persistent logins functionality available in `grails-spring-security-ldap` plugin, because I found it incompatible with my Active Directory tree layout. Most probably, this could be customized by extending `LdapUserDetailsManager` but in my situation I found it unnecessary to store token in database.

I used [regular spring security remember me cookie option](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/remember-me.html#remember-me-hash-token) but without storing user password in the cookie. I extended the following methods from `TokenBasedRememberMeServices`

- `makeTokenSignature` - make token signature without password field
- `processAutoLoginCookie`- if cookie exists, then retrieve username from cookie token and fetch ldap user details (I had to write my own method `retrieveUserFromLdap()` explained later)
- `onLoginSuccess` - this gets triggered when user logs in with remember-me option checked. Here, I'm removing password and saving token signature to cookie.

To fetch user details and roles from LDAP it might depend on specific implementation but my method looks like this:

```
    static protected UserDetails retrieveUserFromLdap(String username) {
    def ldapUserSearch = Holders.applicationContext.getBean('ldapUserSearch')
    def userContextMapper = Holders.applicationContext.getBean('ldapUserDetailsMapper')
    def authoritiesPopulator = Holders.applicationContext.getBean('ldapAuthoritiesPopulator')

    def userContext = ldapUserSearch.searchForUser(username)
    def userAuthorities = authoritiesPopulator.getGrantedAuthorities(userContext,username)
    userContextMapper.mapUserFromContext(userContext,username,userAuthorities)
}
```